# flex image component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image

I want to display a png with flex's builtin image component.

There's a specific x, y that I want this image to be displayed.

How do I do it? I am pretty new to flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. See the online Adobe documentation on [positioning](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_16.html).

```
<mx:Image id="img0" 
            source="@Embed('logo.jpg')" 
            x="40" y="40"/>
```

Of course you can choose not to Embed the image and load it directly from a different URL. I strongly recommend going through the [API documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Image.html).

And always refer to the documentation: [ImageControl](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_16.html)

**Edit:** Using the Image control in AS3 code

```
import mx.controls.Image; 

public function SetImageProperties(url:string, x:int, y:int) : void {
   var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
   var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
   imageLoader.load(image);
   addChild (imageLoader);
   imageLoader.x = x;
   imageLoader.y = y;
```

}

Use a loop/`Repeater` component for multiple images.

Comment: is there a way to do it with code and not xml? the x and y position of the image changes.

And I also want to have multiple of the same images.

Comment: I tried using your code but I don't really understand how to use it. I have some image in my assets folder called image.png.

Do I have to embed it before I call your function?

I am not sure what this URL is either. is it "assets/image.png"?

Comment: Yes, you will need to embed them. Did you go through the documentation? See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/embedding_assets/

Comment: yea. This is my code:

[Embed(source="assets/image.png")]
[Bindable]
public var img:Class; 

Now lets say I want to put it in location 10, 10.

How do I call your method to do what I want?